# Determing if a value in an array is in the past, present or future

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays like so:

```
 const exhibitiontypes = [
  {
   title: 'Past Exhibitions',
   type: 'past',
  },
  {
  title: 'Current Exhibitions',
  type: 'current',
  },
  {
  title: 'Upcoming Exhibitions',
  type: 'upcoming',
},
]
```

And

```
const exhibitions = [
  {
  name: 'Exhibition 1',
  startdate: new Date(2021, 08, 10),
  enddate: new (2021, 08, 15)
  },
  {
  name: 'Exhibition 2',
  startdate: new Date(2020, 08, 13),
  enddate: new Date(2020, 09, 25)
  },
  {
   name: 'Exhibition 3',
   startdate: new Date(),
   enddate: new Date(2021, 08, 5)
  }
 ]
```

And in my app, I map through the exhibition types and return an `exhibitiontypepage`, whcih would contain the past, current or upcoming exhibitions based on the start and end date of each exhibition.

```
const exhibitiontypes.map(type=> {
    return  <Exhibitiontypepage exhibitions={?} type={type}/>
 })
```

How can I filter the array of exhibitions to match only if the exhibition is in the past, present or future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to filter the `exhibitions` before trying to render them. You could achieve this using a reducer function via [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const exhibitions = [
  {
  name: 'Exhibition 1',
  startdate: new Date(2021, 08, 10),
  enddate: new Date(2021, 08, 15)
  },
  {
  name: 'Exhibition 2',
  startdate: new Date(2020, 08, 13),
  enddate: new Date(2020, 09, 25)
  },
  {
   name: 'Exhibition 3',
   startdate: new Date(),
   enddate: new Date(2021, 08, 5)
  }
]

const dateFilteredExhibitions = exhibitions.reduce((result, exb) => {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (now < +exb.startdate) {
    result.upcoming.push(exb);
  } else if (now > +exb.enddate) {
    result.past.push(exb)
  } else {
    result.current.push(exb)
  }
  return result;
}, {past: [], current: [], upcoming: []});

console.log(dateFilteredExhibitions);
```

Where you make this call to `reduce` is up to you. Probably you will do it after fetching the raw data from an API inside a `useEffect` and then something like `setFilteredExhibitions(dateFilteredExhibitions)`.

```
const [filteredExhibitions, setFilteredExhibitions] = React.useState({
  past: [],
  current: [],
  upcoming: []
})
```

If its static data on your local system then you can do this outside the scope of the consuming React component or in a separate file and import it.

Once you have a variable you can reference which holds the filtered objects, the render call can access it by property name:

```
const exhibitiontypes.map(type=> {
    return  <Exhibitiontypepage exhibitions={filteredExhibitions[type.type]} type={type}/>
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to compare to `Date.now()`, which is the current time in milliseconds. The easiest way to convert `Date` objects into milliseconds is to use the [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) (+) to convert to a `Number`. After that, it's just a comparison of numeric values.

```js
const now = Date.now();
exhibitions.map(entry => {
  if (+entry.enddate < now) {
    return exhibitiontypes[0];
  } else if (+entry.startdate <= now && +entry.enddate >= now) {
    return exhibitiontypes[1];
  } else {
    return exhibitiontypes[2];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The below answer shows two concepts:

1. Caching: this seems like a perfect opportunity to filter your data **once** and never do it again (unless you need to via an API call). This ensures a new data structure `exhibitionByType` is pre-filled with the filtered exhibitions and accessed easily anytime you want to see the filtered exhibition data. This is **much** more efficient than filtering every time you click on a button which consumes resources.
2. I added some HTML so it is obvious to you what you will get and how to use it on your implementation. Have fun with it!

```js
const currentDate = new Date(),
      exhibitiontypes = [
        {
         title: 'Past Exhibitions',
         type: 'past',
        },
        {
          title: 'Current Exhibitions',
          type: 'current',
        },
        {
          title: 'Upcoming Exhibitions',
          type: 'upcoming',
        },
      ],
      exhibitions = [
        {
          name: 'Past exhibition',
          startdate: new Date(2000, 08, 10),
          enddate: new Date(2000, 08, 15)
        },
        {
            name: 'Present exhibition',
            startdate: new Date(2020, 08, 13),
            enddate: currentDate
        },
        {
           name: 'Upcoming exhibition',
           startdate: new Date(),
           enddate: new Date(2023, 08, 5)
        }
      ];

// This array will serve as a cache, filtered only once and used continuously throughout the app. Index 0, 1, and 2 will correspond to 'past', 'present' and 'future' respectively
let exhibitionByType = [],
    resultElem = document.getElementById('result');

// Adding an inner array to serve as the list of filtered exhibitions by type
exhibitiontypes.forEach(elem => {
  elem.exhibitionList = [];

  exhibitionByType.push(elem);
});

// Filtering each exhibition by type
exhibitions.forEach(elem => {
  // Present by default
  let index = 1;

  if (currentDate < elem.enddate) {
    // Past
    index = 0;
  } else if (currentDate > elem.enddate) {
    // Future
    index = 2;
  }

  exhibitionByType[index].exhibitionList.push(elem);
});

// Filtering via newly formed exhibitionByType
function getExhibitionListByType (type) {
  resultElem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(exhibitionByType[type]);
};
```

```html
<button onclick="getExhibitionListByType(0)">Past</button>
<button onclick="getExhibitionListByType(1)">Present</button>
<button onclick="getExhibitionListByType(2)">Future</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```